# Auto completion correction

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, controller

I am using auto completion for one of my field

```
   <script>
var tags1 = {!jsonDescriptionData1};
$( "#autocomplete1" ).autocomplete({
  source: function( request, response ) {
          var matcher = new RegExp( "^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex( request.term ), "i" );
          response( $.grep( tags1, function( item ){
              return matcher.test( item );
          }) );
      }
});
</script>
```

Vf code :

```
   <apex:inputText value="{!inputText1}" id="autocomplete1" />
```

It is not showing auto completion.but i can get the value to controller.

html code:

```
<input type="text" Value="{!inputText1}"  id="autocomplete1"/>
```

It is showing auto completion .but i cant able to get the value to controller.

Comment: can you provide your controller code once.

Comment: public String inputText1{get;set;}                                  if(inputText1<>''){
         query +=' WHERE ' + input1 + ' ' + operator + ' : inputText1' ;  }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the ID value used in the selector is not the ID that is generated for the apex:inputText component.  You can see the actual ID if you view the source of your page.

Change

```
$( "#autocomplete1" )
```

to use a partial selector.

```
$( "input[id$=autocomplete1]" )
```

You can still use apex:inputText if you do that.

Alternatively you can use the [$Component global variable](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_variables_global_component.htm) to build the exact ID, but if you change the page structure you may have to change it.

Comment: Additionally don't forget about `jQuery.noConflict();` function if using a `$` notification. Look at [jquery in a visualforce page](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/7884/jquery-in-a-visualforce-page/7898)

Answer (score 0):

Use apex:inputText instead of pure html input box, it seems that your autocomplete1 value is not appearing in form data.